# "Invalid email" in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is an error in my store when trying to checkout or update/delete an order in the admin panel (might appear in other cases).

It shows the error :

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0`

the 'I' refering to first letter of the following sentence of the JSON response :

`Invalid email`

I have re-installed Wordpress, Woocommerce & my theme (Aurum) to the latest version, and repaired database using WordPress tools.

Comment: Possibiy might be a syntax issue of html or php tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching through the code for the sentence “Invalid email”, it appears that it was an error thrown by Mailjet plugin. Deactivating it resolved the issue.